# how to access image from tomcat temp directory

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have uploaded an image in tomcat temp folder using this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            // Creating the directory to store file
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
            File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + name);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
            System.out.println(serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

            logger.info("Server File Location="
                    + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

            return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + name
                + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```

Now I would like to access that image in to jsp page. I tried in this way:

```
<img src="/home/sudeepcv/java work place/Server/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/tmpFiles/img.jpg" width="100%" />
```

but it is not loading. How can I access this by relative path?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serve files outside of your webapp, you will need to read the image again and send it as base64 encoded data, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207190/1113392) for how you can do it and for browser support.

But I would recommend that you put images you upload in some directory our webapp can access, for example `<your-app>/images` and use `<img src="images/img.jpg" width="100%" />` in your HTML.

To know the path of you application you could use [ServletContext#getRealPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)) instead of `System.getProperty("catalina.home")`:

```
String rootPath = context.getRealPath(""); // need access to the ServletContext
```

Although this is a way to do it, you need to know that servlet containers may be configured to not unpack war files, in which case `getRealPath` will not be usefull.